# XSLT Summing Values based on other node values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, sum, xpath-1.0

I am trying to sum some XML values in one node based on a value in another node.

The node in `Entry` that relates to Item is always one `RecordNo` less than the `RecordNo` in `Item`. So the `Entry` with `RecordNo` 1 is related to the Item with `RecordNo` 2.

I want to sum all Item/Cost nodes where `IsValid = 1` for the corresponding Entry Node.
I can only use XSLT version 1.0.

I have tried

```
Sum(../Items/Item[../Entries/Entry[IsValid=1 and RecordNo -1 = ../Entries/Entry/RecordNo]])
```

My desired output from the example below would be 22.

```
<Root>
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Cost>10</Cost>
        <RecordNo>2</RecordNo>
        <Type>1</Type>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Cost>12</Cost>
        <RecordNo>5</RecordNo>
        <Type>1</Type>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Cost>10</Cost>
        <RecordNo>9</RecordNo>
        <Type>2</Type>
    </Item>
</Items>
<Entries>
    <Entry>
        <IsValid>1</IsValid>
        <RecordNo>1</RecordNo>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <IsValid>1</IsValid>
        <RecordNo>4</RecordNo>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <IsValid>0</IsValid>
        <RecordNo>8</RecordNo>
    </Entry>
</Entries>
</Root>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? What should the transform output? Please clarify.

Comment: I have updated the question with my desired output and something I have tried

Comment: Much better now. Please give a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solve with this expression:

```
sum(/Root/Items/Item[RecordNo -1=/Root/Entries/Entry[IsValid=1]/RecordNo]/Cost)
```

The problem with yours is that you are messing up with the context node, remember that any relative path expression in the predicate (the expression you put between the brackets) refers to the current element, the one that will be picked in case the expression evaluates to true.